# ArrayList containing multiple ArrayLists in ViewHolder

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-viewholder

So I have an ArrayList that contains multiple ArrayLists. What I'm trying to do is show all the elements in all of the arraylists. The problem is that the for loop I have created overrides the previous elements.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ContentClickViewHolder holder, int position) {

    int finalPosition = MainActivity.getBasketList().get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).size();
    for (int i = 0; i < finalPosition; i++) {
        final Content object = MainActivity.getBasketList().get(position).get(i);
        final int value = i;

        holder.name.setText(object.getRestaurant_name());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't do this in `onBindViewHolder()` method.
2. Get list from `MainActivity.getBasketList()` make copy of this list

   `List<YourObject> copy = new ArrayList<>(MainActivity.getBasketList());`
3. Make some computation outside of the adapter. It can be activity, or better presenter on that copy.
4. Set that copy as a new data for adapter.

Adapter should just help to display the list, should not have logic to sort list.